# What is the best way to send a file reference through ActiveMQ, when using SpringBoot 1.3.2.RELEASE?

Tags: file, spring-boot, activemq-classic, release

I was using SpringBoot 1.3.1.RELEASE and I was having no problems to send file references through a message in ActiveMQ.

Since I have updated to SpringBoot 1.3.2.RELEASE I have been experimenting a problem.
The activemq client refuse to read the file reference with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class java.io.File! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
at org.apache.activemq.util.ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.checkSecurity(ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java:112) ~[activemq-client-5.12.2.jar:5.12.2]
at org.apache.activemq.util.ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java:57) ~[activemq-client-5.12.2.jar:5.12.2]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:206) ~[activemq-client-5.12.2.jar:5.12.2]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

My only solution to solve this problem was to add the first two lines in the creation of the bean JmsTransactionManager.

```
@Bean
public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf){
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqCf = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory)cf;
    amqCf.setTrustAllPackages(true);                // Without this we are not able to send the object type File.class through a JMS message. This problem started when we migrated to Springboot 1.3.2-RELEASE
    JmsTransactionManager result = new JmsTransactionManager();
    result.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return result;
}
```

Is there a more recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not passing just an URL?

Comment: @user1581366 have you faced with any issues by using `setTrustAllPackages` as described in your question ? I'm also struggling with this issue right now and want to use your solution with `amqCf.setTrustAllPackages(true);`

Comment: @alexanoid, this method has been giving me absolutely no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Java serialization has many security vulnerabilities that expose you to risk.  The updated broker now blacklists most objects and requires you to create a whitelist of the things you want to handle.

Documentation for this is on the [ActiveMQ Website](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html).